# Why hasn't David Gerrold published the next "War against the Chtorr" book yet?

Tags: david-gerrold

Can anybody explain what's holding up the 5th *War Against the Chtorr* book?

*A Rage for Revenge* came out in 1993.   *A Method for Madness*, was supposed to be nearing release in 2015.  [io9 said so.](http://io9.gizmodo.com/david-gerrold-says-the-next-chtorr-book-will-be-finishe-1718362165)   But still.  Nothing

Comment: It's scheduled for release right after Harlan Ellison releases "The Last Dangerous Visions".

Answer (score 9):

The io9 article says that the book would be "finished" in September 2015, which I take to mean that Gerrold would be finished writing it. Indeed, on August 26, 2015, Gerrold [shared on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/david.gerrold/posts/10206332026511886?fref=nf&pnref=story) that he had completed writing the first draft.

> The first draft of A METHOD FOR MADNESS is finished and in the hands of beta-readers.
>
> Editing might take a few more months. But the bulk of the job is done.

I cannot find a more recent progress report than this, but [the FAQ on David Gerrold's website](http://www.gerrold.com/faq/) does address your question directly:

> **Why is it taking so long to complete *A Method for Madness*?**
>
> Good question. All I can say is I’m probably more impatient than you are. I know what scenes and sequences still need to be written, and I know how they have to be written. I keep discovering new things about the Chtorran ecology. I want to work them all in, and I want to keep everything consistent, well-structured, and exciting. It’s hard work.

Comment: Hope you're right.   But the September 2015 date WAS being touted as a the release date two years ago, so, I'm feelin' a little paranoid about this.

Comment: The initial project was sidelined because Gerrold adopted a boy with special needs and raising the child was a higher priority than finishing the book. The experience served as inspiration for his novelette https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Martian_Child, later adapted into a movie: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martian_Child

Comment: @jeffronicus Good information about the initial delays; I assumed the OP was more interested in the recent ones.

Comment: IMO It's never coming out.   Gerrold doesn't know where to go with the story.

Comment: 2021, thought I'd check again .... still nothing.  Quelle surprise!

Comment: 2022 ..... Nope.

Comment: 2023 ..... Nope.

Answer (score 3):

Gerrold is still in the process of writing the book [as of August 2017](https://uk.gofundme.com/a-bubble-in-the-cash-flow), offering donors to a charity the chance to have their name in A Method for Madness.

> DONATION PERK FOR $1000
>
> Anyone making a donation of $1000 or more will receive all of the
>   previous perks, PLUS:
>
> **I will name a character after you in either A NEST FOR NIGHTMARES or A
>   METHOD FOR MADNESS.**

Comment: Note that, in and of itself, this doesn't *necessarily* mean that his statement that [he had completed the first draft two years earlier](https://www.facebook.com/david.gerrold/posts/10206332026511886?fref=nf&pnref=story) is untrue. (Not that I think Valorum was implying it was - simply noting, since [another answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/163166/80867) mentions the Facebook post from 2015).

Comment: @RDFozz - Indeed. This is merely the most recent update I can find and which confirms that the book is still in progress as of 2017.